# MVC sending a form to a page for testing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, actionresult

I am using MVC and have a view (`test.cshtml`) that contains a form.  Is there a way to send it to another View `page.cshtml` for testing instead of same [http] controller `ActionResult test()`?

I am trying to validate that all the form field values are correct before updating db.  Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: you can send it to another `ActionResult` with some other name in the same controller.

Comment: There is an easier way to do that, just put all your validation in your model, then call `ModelState.IsValid` before you save. You can make a form post to whatever controller/action you like by specifying them as parameters in the `Html.BeginForm` call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "Weight", FormMethod.Post))    
//where "Add" is the Action name and Weight is the controller (WeightController) -> http://foo/Weight
{
......
}
```

With a model

```
public class WeightModel
{
    [Required] public string Description { get; set; }
    [Required] public int Weight { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
}
```

In your Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Add(WeightModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) //framwork will validate based on attributes on model
        {
            return View("Index", model);
        }
        else
        {
            //save to db
            return RedirectToAction("Added");
        }
    }
```